# Pass NSString to C++ method

Tags: nsstring, objective-c++, stdstring

I'm trying to pass a NSString to a C++ method and I tried this but it's not working:

```
    trackName = @"name";
    Track track(new String([trackName UTF8String]));
```

I'm writing this code inside an `.mm` file. I also added `#include <string>` at the top of the file but I'm not sure if that's necessary. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? These are the errors that I'm getting:

[image]

And this is the C++ track constructor that I'm calling:

```
Track(const string &aTrackName)
    {
    trackName =  aTrackName;
}
```

Comment: how does it not work...?

Comment: Hard to help without knowing what is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I posted a screenshot with the error messages and the Track constructor.

Comment: I followed this post and was able to successfully pass C strings between C++ and Objective C code: https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/macos-extension-creation-combining-c-with-cocoa-and-objective-c.52174/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your function is expecting a `string` and you're trying to instantiate a `String` object, which it probably knows nothing about.

The other problem with this code is that it expects a string reference but you are passing it a pointer to a string. You can simply pass it a string temporary. Try:

```
Track track(std::string([trackName UTF8String]));
```

Comment: This still isn't working. It's giving me syntax errors, saying there's a missing `[` which I really doubt is the case. Here's a SS: with the errors: http://i47.tinypic.com/25u5ds2.png